# curl error despite --insecure and w/o proxy: ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: ssl, curl, ftps, ftp-server

I'm using git-ftp for deployment of some sites, and with one server I don't manage to establish a connection through TLS.

```
curl -vv --insecure ftps://linux12.unixserver.org:21
* Rebuilt URL to: ftps://linux12.unixserver.org:21/
*   Trying 212.63.145.118...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to linux12.unixserver.org (212.63.145.118) port 21 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

I already found several other questions, but my issue doesn't match.

- I'm not using a proxy
- Even `--insecure` will fail, so it can't be a cert trust issue
- I tried `--cacert` as well, doesn't work
- `--tls-max 1.2` will change version to 1.2, but it doesn't change anything

Some source states that this error also occurs when the server doesn't deliver a cert at all.

```
openssl s_client -connect linux12.unixserver.org:21 -starttls ftp
```

Delivers a certificate, so that seems to be alright.

I can successfully connect by means of Nautilus, but it's warning me about the certificate, that the issuer is unknown.

Thanks very much for any hint on what else to try.

Comment: I'm verifying more with `s_client` and the ftp server seems to only deliver the server certificate. I would expect `--insecure` to look over that fact. I'm verifying with the hosting provider.

Comment: FTPS is probably wrong on port 21. You probably want FTP:// with `--ssl` to make it upgrade the connection.

Comment: Thx Daniel. I forgot to mention that the connection from Nautilus on port 21 works. It's asking me if I want to connect despite a misconfigured certificate.

Comment: `curl -vv --ssl …` results in the same error.

Comment: IF the intermediate certificate is missing in the delivered chain, shouldn't --cacert solve this?

Comment: I'm still playing around, and s_client provides an error. BUT curl apparently also knows a matching error `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.`, which I don't get.

Comment: @DanielStenberg seems to be right here. use `curl -vv --insecure --ssl ftp://linux12.unixserver.org:21`

Comment: Hi @DanielStenberg. That works, but it's an obsolete option, and I'm pretty sure that it only works because it "reverts to a non-secure connection if the server doesn't support SSL/TLS" ):

Comment: What's obsolete about that? If you want curl to require it, use `--ssl-reqd`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the documentation, obsolete was referring to a different option.

Comment: Ok, one step further. `--ssl` works and does establish the secure connection, while `ftps://` still fails. Do you have an idea why? What's the difference?

Comment: So `--ssl` uses _explicit SSL_, which means it connects insecurely first, and then asks the server to STARTTLS. `ftps://` will try to connect securely through TLS first, and then talk FTP. I think that's the main answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually two issues were involved in this case.

1) `ftps` is the wrong protocol for servers that only support *explicit tls*.

The right protocol would be `ftpes`. If curl is not compiled with support for it, you can use `--ssl-reqd` to enforce TLS, or just `--ssl`.

In context of *git-ftp* it works even if curl is compiled w/o `ftpes`.

2) The server didn't deliver a valid certificate chain, so the certificate could not be validated.

This is currently a [ftp certificate bug in plesk](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003871553-Error-is-shown-when-accessing-a-server-via-FTP-The-server-s-certificate-is-unknown-Please-carefully-examine-the-certificate-to-make-sure-the-server-can-be-trusted).

The solution is to retrieve the certificate chain manually and provide the chain by means of `--cacert <file>`. If it's self-signed, extract the public key and use `--pinnedpubkey <file>`.

Thanks very much to Daniel Stenberg for the right hints.